# FD and liquidation of cooperative Bank (patsanstha) in India

Tags: india, banking, deposit-insurance

I've my money stuck in cooperative patsanstha (bank) since last 4-5 years. Money was invested across multiple FDs (worth Rs. 1,50,000) and after banks liquidation they deposited the money to saving account with passbook.
There is an administrator appointed who sits at taluka place (30-40kms away). And post liquidation so far I've got 10k,15k,10k back every year after a lot of follow up but now they have stopped it. I'm in need of money due to medical emergency and need to get entire amount. For the same having following queries:
1. Whats the procedure to withdraw all money.
2. Is there any protection RBI offers to such trapped customers/investors?
3. Since the money is with them since last 4-5 years what interest rates are applicable.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Most cooperative banks are [insured upto Rs 1,00,000/-](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/FAQView.aspx?Id=64) . 
It depends on what is the current status of the Bank and withdrawal of the funds would be based on the decision taken by the administrator. There maybe no interest payable, it would again be decided by the administrator.